# Add 4 multiple credentials in Power Query Connector Authentication

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I am trying to request multiple credentials from user in Power Query Connector.

I have tried the following.

```
Test = [
    Authentication = [
        UsernamePassword= [
            Fields = [
                Username = [
                    Label = "Username"
                ],
                Password = [
                    Label = "Password",
                    Type = Password.Type
                ],
                ClientId = [
                    Label = "Client Id"
                ],
                ClientSecret = [
                    Label = "Client Secret",
                    Type = Password.Type
                ]
            ],
            Label = "Custom"
        ]
    ]
];
```

When I am trying to Set credentials in VsCode power query SDK. It only ask for Username and Password. I need to ask for two more credentials i.e. `Client Id` and `Client Secret`

I can not find relevant documentation for this scenario.